# Multiple Hibernate transactions in a JTA session

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, wildfly, jta

I would like to have multiple Hibernate transactions in a single EJB method call (running in WildFly). Currently my *current_session_context_class* is set to **jta** and *transaction.factory_class* is **org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory**.

Now, for example, the following code fails:

```
public void myMethod(){
   try{
      Transaction tr = myHibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
      //execute some DB operation
      tr.commit();

      tr = myHibernateSessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
      //execute some DB operation
      tr.commit();

   }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

The problem is that the second call to *beginTransaction()* throws an exception **org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction instance is no longer valid.**

How do I get a new transaction for the current session?